# Google embedded assistant service gives an error about text_config missing when it is included

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

I'm trying to use the embedded Google Assistant service (https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/reference/rpc/google.assistant.embedded.v1alpha2) to send some text queries from an app I'm writing in Rust. As there's no official client library and I haven't been able to get either of the GRPC libraries I've tried working, I'm POSTing an AssistRequest proto directly to https://embeddedassistant.googleapis.com/$rpc/google.assistant.embedded.v1alpha2.EmbeddedAssistant/Assist. After getting the appropriate OAuth token and registering a device ID, I send a proto like this:

```
config {
  text_query: "what's the time"
  audio_out_config {
    encoding: MP3
    sample_rate_hertz: 16000
  }
  screen_out_config {
    screen_mode: PLAYING
  }
  dialog_state_in {
    language_code: "en-US"
  }
  device_config {
    device_id: "my_device_id"
    device_model_id: "<my model id>"
  }
}
```

(with a valid device_id and device_model_id filled in). However, I always get a 400 back, with the error

> "Invalid \'AssistConfig\': `audio_in_config` or `text_query` must be provided."

Why am I getting this error, when `text_query` is clearly filled in? I get the same error if I try setting `audio_in_config`.

Comment: How are you serializing the proto fields? Are you sending a JSON body in your POST?

Comment: No, just sending a proto with the normal binary serialisation, following the documentation at https://googleapis.github.io/HowToRPC#grpc-fallback-experimental and the example at https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis.github.io/blob/master/examples/rpc/rust/src/main.rs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, it turned out I needed to wrap the request in a `StreamBody` [proto](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/blob/master/net/grpc/gateway/protos/stream_body.proto), putting the serialised `AssistRequest` in the **message** field. This was not documented anywhere I could see though!

Comment: I am trying to do the same using python and facing issue as described by you. Could you please elaborate on the solution.

Comment: Create the `AssistRequest`, serialise it to bytes as usual. Create a `StreamBody`, put the serialised `AssistRequest` in its `message` field, serialise that to bytes. Send the serialised `StreamBody` in your HTTP POST body.

Comment: See `send_assistant_request` and `encode_request` in https://gitlab.com/qwandor/qbutton/-/blob/master/src/assistant/assistant.cpp for my C++ implementation for ESP8266.